# How to paste a string on each element of a vector of strings using apply in R?

Tags: r, paste, apply

I have a vector of strings.

```
d <- c("Mon","Tues","Wednes","Thurs","Fri","Satur","Sun")
```

for which I want to paste the string "day" on each element of the vector in a way similar to this.

```
week <- apply(d, "day", paste, sep='')
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

No need for `apply()`, just use `paste()`:

```
R> d <- c("Mon","Tues","Wednes","Thurs","Fri","Satur","Sun")
R> week <- paste(d, "day", sep="")
R> week
[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  
[4] "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Sunday"   
R>
```

Comment: Shorter form: `week <- paste0(d, "day")`

Comment: Sure. But please account for the fact that `paste0()` did *not* exist when I wrote the answer six years ago.

Answer (score 14):

Other have already indicated that since `paste` is vectorised, there is no need to use `apply` in this case.

However, to answer your question:  `apply` is used for an array or data.frame.  When you want to apply a function over a list (or a vector) then use `lapply` or `sapply` (a variant of `lapply` that *simplifies* the results):

```
sapply(d, paste, "day", sep="")
        Mon        Tues      Wednes       Thurs         Fri       Satur 
   "Monday"   "Tuesday" "Wednesday"  "Thursday"    "Friday"  "Saturday" 
        Sun 
   "Sunday"
```

Comment: @pedrosaurio I have to point out that if you use `sapply` for this specific problem it would be hugely inefficient.  Use the already vectorised form of `paste`, as @DirkEddelbuettel suggested.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks, I was at first a bit confused for which answer I should tick as the good one. As Andrie's answer was the 'real' answer I thought that it should be selected as the good one but if it is a wrong method and it will create confusion for future reference I'll then change it. Thanks again

Answer (score 7):

Apart from `paste`/`paste0` there are variety of ways in which we can add a string to every element in the vector.

1) Using `sprintf`

```
sprintf("%sday", d)
#[1] "Monday"    "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"  "Saturday"  "Sunday"
```

2) `glue`

```
glue::glue("{d}days")
```

Here `{d}` is evaluated as R code. This can be wrapped in `as.character` if needed.

3) `str_c` in `stringr`

```
stringr::str_c(d, "day")
```

whose equivalent is

4) `stri_c` in `stringi`

```
stringi::stri_c(d, "day")
```

5) `stringi` also has `stri_paste`

```
stringi::stri_paste(d, "day")
```