# Paste multiple columns together

Tags: r, paste, r-faq

I have a bunch of columns in a dataframe which I want to paste together (seperated by "-") as follows:

```
data <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 
                   'b' = c('a','b','c'), 
                   'c' = c('d', 'e', 'f'), 
                   'd' = c('g', 'h', 'i'))
i.e.     
     a   b   c  d  
     1   a   d   g  
     2   b   e   h  
     3   c   f   i
```

Which I want to become:

```
a x  
1 a-d-g  
2 b-e-h  
3 c-f-i
```

I could normally do this with:

```
within(data, x <- paste(b,c,d,sep='-'))
```

and then removing the old columns, but unfortunately I do not know the names of the columns specifically, only a collective name for all of the columns, e.g. I would know that `cols <- c('b','c','d')`

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
# your starting data..
data <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 'b' = c('a','b','c'), 'c' = c('d', 'e', 'f'), 'd' = c('g', 'h', 'i')) 

# columns to paste together
cols <- c( 'b' , 'c' , 'd' )

# create a new column `x` with the three columns collapsed together
data$x <- apply( data[ , cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" )

# remove the unnecessary columns
data <- data[ , !( names( data ) %in% cols ) ]
```

Comment: no  need for apply here; paste is vectorised, and that's more efficient

Comment: @baptiste ..possible without `do.call`?

Comment: sure, you could for example use `evil(parse(...))`, but I believe `do.call` is the right call here.

Comment: Do.call here is the better technique; maintains the vectorization.

Comment: hmm.. how would you pass the `collapse = "-"` through? to `paste`?

Comment: Funnily when I merge 2 columns (1 factorized and 1 numeric), where second column goes from 1 to 12 (2 digit!), I get a space between separator and second part e.g. "Blue_ 1", "Blue_ 2" instead of "Blue_1", "Blue_2". This problem doesn't occur with do.call. If the second column is only single digits, no space is introduced.

Comment: worked perfectly. it does need apply or some variant of it to concatenate several columns for which column names are unknown into a single column. [Other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984796/how-to-paste-a-string-on-each-element-of-a-vector-of-strings-using-apply-in-r) did not work for me. Also [lapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723493/apply-paste-over-a-list-of-vectors-to-get-a-list-of-strings) did not work.

Comment: @baptiste if you mean paste(data, collapse = "-" ) that would return a single string

Comment: Could yo please explain what 1 means here? `apply( data[ , cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" )`

Answer (score 57):

As a variant on [baptiste's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14568822/892313), with `data` defined as you have and the columns that you want to put together defined in `cols`

```
cols <- c("b", "c", "d")
```

You can add the new column to `data` and delete the old ones with

```
data$x <- do.call(paste, c(data[cols], sep="-"))
for (co in cols) data[co] <- NULL
```

which gives

```
> data
  a     x
1 1 a-d-g
2 2 b-e-h
3 3 c-f-i
```

Comment: Is there a comma missing in "c(data[cols],..."? Like so: "c(data[,cols],..."

Comment: @roschu Either will work. Indexing a `data.frame` with a single character vector will be a column indexing, despite the first argument usually being the row index.

Comment: fast and smart. Thank you

Answer (score 54):

Using `tidyr` package, this can be easily handled in 1 function call.

```
data <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 
                   'b' = c('a','b','c'), 
                   'c' = c('d', 'e', 'f'), 
                   'd' = c('g', 'h', 'i'))
```

Exclude first column, everything else gets pasted.

```
# tidyr_0.6.3

unite(data, newCol, -a) 
# or by column index unite(data, newCol, -1)

#   a newCol
# 1 1  a_d_g
# 2 2  b_e_h
# 3 3  c_f_i
```

Comment: I think OP mentioned they don't know the column name in advance., otherwise the could do it with just `within(data, x <- paste(b,c,d,sep='-'))` as they illustrated.

Comment: I agree with @DavidArenburg, this doesn't address the OP's situation.  I think `unite_(data, "b_c_d", cols)` would, or depending on their actual data.frame, `unite(data, b_c_d, -a)` might be a candidate as well.

Answer (score 15):

I'd construct a new data.frame:

```
d <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 'b' = c('a','b','c'), 'c' = c('d', 'e', 'f'), 'd' = c('g', 'h', 'i')) 

cols <- c( 'b' , 'c' , 'd' )

data.frame(a = d[, 'a'], x = do.call(paste, c(d[ , cols], list(sep = '-'))))
```

Comment: note that instead of `d[ , cols]` you may want to use `d[ , names(d) != 'a']` if all but the `a` column are to be pasted together.

Comment: One of the canonical solutions on SO, I think you could shorten this to `cbind(a = d['a'], x = do.call(paste, c(d[cols], sep = '-')))`, e.g. avoid the commas, `list` and `data.frame` while using the `data.frame` method of `cbind`

Answer (score 10):

Just to add additional solution with `Reduce` which probably is slower than `do.call` but probebly better than `apply` because it will avoid the `matrix` conversion. Also, instead a `for` loop we could just use `setdiff` in order to remove unwanted columns

```
cols <- c('b','c','d')
data$x <- Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep = "-"), data[cols])
data[setdiff(names(data), cols)]
#   a     x
# 1 1 a-d-g
# 2 2 b-e-h
# 3 3 c-f-i
```

---

Alternatively we could update `data` in place using the `data.table` package (assuming fresh data)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, x := Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep = "-"), .SD[, mget(cols)])]
data[, (cols) := NULL]
data
#    a     x
# 1: 1 a-d-g
# 2: 2 b-e-h
# 3: 3 c-f-i
```

Another option is to use `.SDcols` instead of `mget` as in

```
setDT(data)[, x := Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep = "-"), .SD), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion the `sprintf`-function deserves a place among these answers as well. You can use `sprintf` as follows:

```
do.call(sprintf, c(d[cols], '%s-%s-%s'))
```

which gives:

```
 [1] "a-d-g" "b-e-h" "c-f-i"
```

And to create the required dataframe:

```
data.frame(a = d$a, x = do.call(sprintf, c(d[cols], '%s-%s-%s')))
```

giving:

```
  a     x
1 1 a-d-g
2 2 b-e-h
3 3 c-f-i
```

Although `sprintf` doesn't have a clear advantage over the `do.call`/`paste` combination of @BrianDiggs, it is especially usefull when you also want to pad certain parts of desired string or when you want to specify the number of digit. See `?sprintf` for the several options.

Another variant would be to use `pmap` from [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr):

```
pmap(d[2:4], paste, sep = '-')
```

Note: this `pmap` solution only works when the columns aren't factors.

---

A benchmark on a larger dataset:

```
# create a larger dataset
d2 <- d[sample(1:3,1e6,TRUE),]
# benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  docp = do.call(paste, c(d2[cols], sep="-")),
  appl = apply( d2[, cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" ),
  tidr = tidyr::unite_(d2, "x", cols, sep="-")$x,
  docs = do.call(sprintf, c(d2[cols], '%s-%s-%s')),
  times=10)
```

results in:

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 docp  214.1786  226.2835  297.1487  241.6150  409.2495  493.5036    10 a  
 appl 3832.3252 4048.9320 4131.6906 4072.4235 4255.1347 4486.9787    10   c
 tidr  206.9326  216.8619  275.4556  252.1381  318.4249  407.9816    10 a  
 docs  413.9073  443.1550  490.6520  453.1635  530.1318  659.8400    10  b
```

---

Used data:

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c('a','b','c'), c = c('d','e','f'), d = c('g','h','i'))
```

Comment: This is my preferred answer since sprintf allows (like paste) to insert a different string between each variables, not just one like "-" or "_", so having like sprintf, c(d2[cols], '%s (%s) some other text here %s ')

Answer (score 8):

I benchmarked the answers of Anthony Damico, Brian Diggs and data_steve on a small sample `tbl_df` and got the following results.

```
> data <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 
+                    'b' = c('a','b','c'), 
+                    'c' = c('d', 'e', 'f'), 
+                    'd' = c('g', 'h', 'i'))
> data <- tbl_df(data)
> cols <- c("b", "c", "d")
> microbenchmark(
+     do.call(paste, c(data[cols], sep="-")),
+     apply( data[ , cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" ),
+     tidyr::unite_(data, "x", cols, sep="-")$x,
+     times=1000
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                                         expr     min      lq      mean  median       uq       max neval
do.call(paste, c(data[cols], sep = "-"))       65.248  78.380  93.90888  86.177  99.3090   436.220  1000
apply(data[, cols], 1, paste, collapse = "-") 223.239 263.044 313.11977 289.514 338.5520   743.583  1000
tidyr::unite_(data, "x", cols, sep = "-")$x   376.716 448.120 556.65424 501.877 606.9315 11537.846  1000
```

However, when I evaluated on my own `tbl_df` with ~1 million rows and 10 columns the results were quite different.

```
> microbenchmark(
+     do.call(paste, c(data[c("a", "b")], sep="-")),
+     apply( data[ , c("a", "b") ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" ),
+     tidyr::unite_(data, "c", c("a", "b"), sep="-")$c,
+     times=25
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                                                       expr        min         lq      mean     median        uq       max neval
do.call(paste, c(data[c("a", "b")], sep="-"))                 930.7208   951.3048  1129.334   997.2744  1066.084  2169.147    25
apply( data[ , c("a", "b") ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" )  9368.2800 10948.0124 11678.393 11136.3756 11878.308 17587.617    25
tidyr::unite_(data, "c", c("a", "b"), sep="-")$c              968.5861  1008.4716  1095.886  1035.8348  1082.726  1759.349    25
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a fairly unconventional (but fast) approach: use `fwrite` from `data.table` to "paste" the columns together, and `fread` to read it back in. For convenience, I've written the steps as a function called `fpaste`:

```
fpaste <- function(dt, sep = ",") {
  x <- tempfile()
  fwrite(dt, file = x, sep = sep, col.names = FALSE)
  fread(x, sep = "\n", header = FALSE)
}
```

Here's an example:

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = c('a','b','c'), c = c('d','e','f'), d = c('g','h','i')) 
cols = c("b", "c", "d")

fpaste(d[cols], "-")
#       V1
# 1: a-d-g
# 2: b-e-h
# 3: c-f-i
```

How does it perform?

```
d2 <- d[sample(1:3,1e6,TRUE),]
  
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  docp = do.call(paste, c(d2[cols], sep="-")),
  tidr = tidyr::unite_(d2, "x", cols, sep="-")$x,
  docs = do.call(sprintf, c(d2[cols], '%s-%s-%s')),
  appl = apply( d2[, cols ] , 1 , paste , collapse = "-" ),
  fpaste = fpaste(d2[cols], "-")$V1,
  dt2 = as.data.table(d2)[, x := Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep = "-"), .SD), .SDcols = cols][],
  times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr        min         lq      mean     median         uq       max neval
#    docp  215.34536  217.22102  220.3603  221.44104  223.27224  225.0906    10
#    tidr  215.19907  215.81210  220.7131  220.09636  225.32717  229.6822    10
#    docs  281.16679  285.49786  289.4514  286.68738  290.17249  312.5484    10
#    appl 2816.61899 3106.19944 3259.3924 3266.45186 3401.80291 3804.7263    10
#  fpaste   88.57108   89.67795  101.1524   90.59217   91.76415  197.1555    10
#     dt2  301.95508  310.79082  384.8247  316.29807  383.94993  874.4472    10
```

Comment: What if you write and read to ramdisk? Comparison would be a little bit more fair.

Comment: @jangorecki, not sure if I'm doing it correctly (I started R with `TMPDIR=/dev/shm R`) but I don't notice a huge difference in comparison to these results. I also haven't played around at all with the number of threads used for `fread` or `fwrite` to see how it affects the results.

Answer (score 6):

Simple and straightforward code with `unite` from `{tidyr} v1.2.0`

## Solution with `{tidyr v1.2.0}`

```
library(tidyr)

data %>% unite("x", all_of(cols), remove = T, sep = "-")
```

- `"x"` is the name of the new column.
- `all_of(cols)` is a selection of what columns we want to merge. Using `<tidy-select>` the column names don't need to be hardcoded in.
- `remove = T` we remove the input columns
- `sep = "-"` we define the separator between values
- if there is `NA`, we can also add `na.rm = TRUE`

#### Output

```
#   a     x
# 1 1 a-d-g
# 2 2 b-e-h
# 3 3 c-f-i
```

#### Input Data

```
data <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 
                   'b' = c('a','b','c'), 
                   'c' = c('d', 'e', 'f'), 
                   'd' = c('g', 'h', 'i'))
cols <- c('b','c','d')
data

#   a b c d
# 1 1 a d g
# 2 2 b e h
# 3 3 c f i
```

*This solution is different from what already posted.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but thought that I should anyway present the simple solution using the paste() function as suggested to by the questioner:

```
data_1<-data.frame(a=data$a,"x"=paste(data$b,data$c,data$d,sep="-")) 
data_1
  a     x
1 1 a-d-g
2 2 b-e-h
3 3 c-f-i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(plyr)

ldply(apply(data, 1, function(x) data.frame(
                      x = paste(x[2:4],sep="",collapse="-"))))

#      x
#1 a-d-g
#2 b-e-h
#3 c-f-i

#  and with just the vector of names you have:

ldply(apply(data, 1, function(x) data.frame(
                      x = paste(x[c('b','c','d')],sep="",collapse="-"))))

# or equally:
mynames <-c('b','c','d')
ldply(apply(data, 1, function(x) data.frame(
                      x = paste(x[mynames],sep="",collapse="-"))))
```