# R data.table column wildcard with sprintf

Tags: r, data.table

Given a `data.table` with an arbitrary number of columns

```
dt = data.table( a = letters[1:5], b = rep('-', 5), c = LETTERS[1:5] )
#    a b c
# 1: a - A
# 2: b - B
# 3: c - C
# 4: d - D
# 5: e - E
```

and an arbitrary `format` string having a number of placeholders corresponding to the number of columns

```
format = '%s0%s1%s'
```

How to apply `sprintf` without explicitly calling it with all column names?
Just provide the `data.table` won't work because `sprintf` expects 3 arguments in this case. Calling `sprintf(format, dt$a, dt$b, dt$b)` is no option because I don't know neither the `format` nor the `data.table` beforehand.
Also `sapply` on row indices won't work because the operation has to be done on a subset of rows preserving their order.

```
idx = seq( 1, by = 2, to = 5 )
```

So the goal is by issueing a hypothetical command

```
dt[ idx, sprintf( format, * )]
```

achieving this

```
# [1] "a0-1A" "c0-1C" "e0-1E"
```

It can be done by calling

```
cols = paste( names( dt ) ), collapse=',' )
# "a,b,c"
eval( parse( text = sprintf( 'dt[ idx, sprintf( format,%s )]', cols ) ) )
# [1] "a0-1A" "c0-1C" "e0-1E"
```

But this is rather arcane and definetly not clean code and it would be nice if there was a more semantic way in the `data.table` package itself.
So the question is basically if there is one. Until now neither google nor the the `data.table` manual gave me an answer.
Furthermore I do neither want to `paste` some/multiple columns but I want to use all columns instead nor I am looking for a way to achieve this by the use of `data.frame`. I am looking for smooth `data.table` syntax.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568662/paste-multiple-columns-together

Comment: @DavidArenburg edited question now to clearly distuingish between that thread and mine. The questions are quite different and my problem is not adressed in that thread.

Comment: Well, the answers on that tread are using pretty much the same syntax as in the answers in the linked thread. I don't see much difference - if any. But I haven't closed your question, rather just recommended that you will also visit the other thread.

Comment: Well, [it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33015233/3001626). And you just need to read some `data.table` tutorial. Doing `do.call(paste0, .SD)` is pretty much the same as doing `do.call(paste0, dt)`. Same goes for `Reduce`

Comment: So one answer - yours - matches my needs, but it's kind of confusing to find it there. Especially if it's so low ranked. 
Therefore I find it useful to have a thread targeting that exact question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste multiple columns together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568662/paste-multiple-columns-together)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do this by passing `sprintf` as argument in `do.call`

```
dt[, do.call(sprintf, c(.SD, fmt = format))]
#[1] "a-A" "b-B" "c-C" "d-D" "e-E"
```

If we need to create this as a column in 'dt', assign (`:=`) it to create the new column

```
dt[, newCol := do.call(sprintf, c(.SD, fmt = format))]
```

We can also use the `paste` with `do.call`

```
dt[, newCol := do.call(paste0, .SD)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `Reduce` and `paste0`:

```
dt[, abc := Reduce(paste0, .SD)]
```

which gives:

```
   a b c abc
1: a - A a-A
2: b - B b-B
3: c - C c-C
4: d - D d-D
5: e - E e-E
```

On a large dataset this is a tiny bit slower than the `do.call`/`sprintf` or `do.call`/`paste0` methods:

```
akrun1 <- dt[sample.int(5, 1e6, TRUE)]
akrun2 <- copy(akrun)
jaap <- copy(akrun)

> system.time(akrun1[, newCol := do.call(sprintf, c(.SD, fmt = format))])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.280   0.002   0.282 
> system.time(akrun2[, newCol := do.call(paste0, .SD)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.187   0.001   0.188 
> system.time(jaap[, abc := Reduce(paste0, .SD)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.325   0.002   0.327
```

Comment: TY, but that doesn't fit the needs of using a `format` string. Though the format string I chose - by means of simplicity - matches the `paste0` semantic it was not what I had actually in mind. 
But it might become handy anyway.

Comment: @SebastianGross I agree that using `sprintf` is more convenint when using a less straightforward format-string. For your next question: It is always good to make the example in your question as close as possible to your real problem.