# How to Concatenate a vectors in R

Tags: r

I have 3 vectors: `state.name`, `state.abb`, `state,area`.
i want to concatenate them to one vector in which every index looks like that:

```
s[1]

[1] "AL - Alabama - 51609 Sq. Mile"
```

how can i merge them to look like this?

Comment: Take a look at `?paste`

Comment: or look at `?sprintf`

Comment: Or `?str_c` from package `stringr` using collapse=" - "

Comment: I think this is element-wise concatenation, so the `collapse` argument is unnecessary (`sep = ' - '` would be useful) and that's not the correct duplicate.

Comment: but I need to create a vector before I use paste. Every index of this vector should consist the three these vector as a string. As you can see the first index of the "s" vector have a combination of these vectors.

Comment: Use `paste`: `v1 <- letters[1:3]
v2 <- letters[4:6]
v3 <- letters[7:9]
v <- paste(v1, v2, v3, sep = " - ")
v[1]`

Comment: You have vectors, right? `state.name`, `state.abb`, `state.area`? `paste` creates the vector. `s = paste(state.abb, state.name, state.area, sep = " - ")`

Comment: Despite your vectors not being in a data frame (you could put them there...) I think this is the best dupe: [paste multiple columns together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14568662/903061).

Comment: And I think you are confused with the *index* of the vector and the *contents* of the vector. The *index* is **always a number**, starting with 1, going to the number of elements in the vector. The *contents* are the things (strings in this case) contained in each element.

Comment: it  works, thanks man:))