# R add column for sparkline with value from each row vector

Tags: r, sparklines

Start with a dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparkline)
df <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))

   X1 X2 X3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
```

Would like to add a column 'spark' for use with sparkline:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(spark = spk_chr(values = ?, type = "bar", elementId = X1))
```

So the question mark (?) would be replaced by a vector made up of each row of df.

For the first row, `? = c(1, 4, 7)`, the values from the first row, `spark = spk(values = c(1, 4, 7)...)`

I know how to extract a vector from any row, first row vector is `unlist(df[1,])`, but do not understand if this can be used in mutate.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568662/paste-multiple-columns-together

Comment: `df %>% mutate(spark = spk_chr(values = c(X1, X2, X3), type = "bar", elementId = X1))`?

Comment: @Axeman That did not work - it gave the same value for each row.  Tried Vectorize(spk_chr) and this changed the elementId, however the values were incorrect for each row.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your goal is here. How can you plot a bar for each row, with three separate elements in each row? Do you want to plot the sum?

Comment: @RonakShah - with your suggestion I created a column of strings that concat each row of values.  Then used strsplit in the values argument for spk_chr.  This worked.  Not sure if there is a more direct approach to avoid string intermediate stage.

Answer (score 1):

Used Ronak's suggestion to create intermediate column:

```
cols = names(df)
df$y <- apply(df[,cols], 1, paste, collapse = "-")
```

Then created vectorized spk_chr:

```
sparky <- Vectorize(sparkline::spk_chr)
```

To use in making the spark column:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(spark = sparky(strsplit(y, split="-"), type = "bar", elementId = X1))
```