# Element wise concatenation of nested list

Tags: r

I have a nested list

```
l1 <- letters
l2 <- 1:26
l3 <- LETTERS
list <- list(l1,l2,l3)
```

Is there an elegant way to concatenate all the elements in inner vectors to form one character vector (possibly using `paste`), the assumption is that all the inner vectors are of the same length.

I would like my final result to be

```
[1] "a1A"
[2] "b2B"
[3] "c3C"
[4] "d4D"
....
[26] "z26Z"
```

Comment: `do.call(paste0, list)`

Comment: this one's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
apply(sapply(list,paste0),1,paste0,collapse="")
[1] "a1A"  "b2B"  "c3C"  "d4D"  "e5E"  "f6F"  "g7G"  "h8H"  "i9I"  "j10J" "k11K" "l12L" "m13M" "n14N" "o15O" [16] "p16P" "q17Q" "r18R" "s19S" "t20T" "u21U" "v22V" "w23W" "x24X" "y25Y" "z26Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

user20650's solution is probably as elegant as you are going to get. But for what it's worth, here's a quick hack in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

ll <- list(l1,l2,l3) # I try not to use "list" as a name. Gets confusing sometimes.

as.data.frame(ll) %>% 
  mutate(x = paste0(.[[1]], .[[2]], .[[3]])) %>% 
  .$x

# returns
 [1] "a1A"  "b2B"  "c3C"  "d4D"  "e5E"  "f6F"  "g7G"  "h8H"  "i9I"  "j10J" "k11K" "l12L"
[13] "m13M" "n14N" "o15O" "p16P" "q17Q" "r18R" "s19S" "t20T" "u21U" "v22V" "w23W" "x24X"
[25] "y25Y" "z26Z"
```

Comment: Even easier: `purrr::pmap(ll, paste0)` ([see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489994/2204410)).