# Programming with mutate to create new data column

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

There is a `data.frame` like so:

```
df <- data.frame("Config" = c("C1","C1","C2","C2"), "SN1" = 1:4, "SN2" = 5:8)
```

I'm trying to make `df %<>% mutate` more generic. Here is an example:

```
df %<>%
  mutate(
    Tag=paste(
      Config,
      as.character(SN1),
      as.character(SN2),
      sep="_"
    )
  )
```

What is desired is to pass a vector `c("Config", "SN1", "SN2")` to the above `mutate` or an alternative that does the same job, namely inserting new column `Tag` into the above `data.frame`. Thank you for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568662/paste-multiple-columns-together  ?

Comment: I think this actually isn't an `%<>%` question, since it would be the same issue with any operator and any function. Rather it's a non-standard evaluation question on [programming with and extending `dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Also `tidyr::unite` is a function to do exactly what you're using here, but I suppose that might just be an example you're using of a broader ability to pass/create columns to a function like `mutate` dynamically

Comment: @Ronak Shah: Thank you. This resolves this problem.

Comment: @camille: yes agree this is not related specifically to `%<>%`. Yes agree a broader ability to pass/create columns to `mutate` dynamically would be very beneficial. Something alone the lines: `eval this code within mutate and get what you want`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in a comment, this isn't a question about the operator `%<>%` but about using non-standard evaluation (NSE) in a `dplyr` function. There's a [pretty good vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) on this, but it's still pretty tricky to get the hang of NSE/tidy evaluation.

Also as I mentioned, what you're doing as an example is exactly what `tidyr::unite` does, so if that were all you needed, you don't actually need to write anything. But it's a good simple example to use.

In this function `custom_unite`, the first argument is `.data`, the data frame being operated on (the custom for being able to pipe is for the first argument to be the data frame). Then `...` captures a flexible number of bare column names to be pasted together, `new_col` is the bare column name of the column to create, and `sep` is passed along as-is to `paste`. (I inadvertently switched the order of arguments from `tidyr::unite`, which takes `col, ...` instead of `..., new_col`.)

You need to create quosures of your columns. For the single bare column `new_col`, you can use `enquo`, but for the flexible number of columns you use `quos` on `...`, which you'll then splice with `!!!`.

To create a new column, you'll assign with `:=` instead of `=` to the unquoted quosure.

```r
library(tidyverse)

custom_unite <- function(.data, ..., new_col, sep = "_") {
  cols <- quos(...)
  new_col_quo <- enquo(new_col)

  .data %>%
    mutate(!!new_col_quo := paste(!!!cols, sep = sep))
}

df %>%
  custom_unite(Config, SN1, SN2, new_col = Tag)
#>   Config SN1 SN2    Tag
#> 1     C1   1   5 C1_1_5
#> 2     C1   2   6 C1_2_6
#> 3     C2   3   7 C2_3_7
#> 4     C2   4   8 C2_4_8
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>