# How do I optimize this row-wise paste in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 1.6M rows and almost 400 columns. I'm trying to create a key for every row by concatenating the column values:

```
paste(df[, c(15:400)], collapse = "_")
```

This is taking forever, and I'm wondering if there is a faster way to perform this action? All the columns are just 0 or 1 values and the key would look something like "0_0_1_0_1_1_0_1...".

Comment: There are lot of options here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568662/paste-multiple-columns-together did you try them ?

Comment: Do you want to paste each row's values together to get one value per row?

Comment: `apply(mtcars[,3:5], 1, paste, collapse="_")`

Comment: can i safely say that your real problem is to create a key for every row based on 386 columns?

Comment: Seconding this^. If your key contains all of your data, then it's hardly a key.

Comment: `do.call(paste,c(sep="-",df[15:400]))`

Comment: Why not just number the rows sequentially? Can you explain your goal that is motivating the idea of copying all the data again into one column?