# how to concatenate vectors of strings in a dataframe

Tags: r, string, vector, concatenation

I was wondering if anyone could help me concencate two vectors of strings:

For example:
hello and hi, that repeat 130 times in a dataframe.

When in the dataframe column I would like for the order to be hello, (130 times) followed by hi (also 130 times), then hello (130 more times), then hi (130 times) again. So they should appear 4 times total (2 times each in order)

This is what I tried so far but it does not seem to work

```
hello <- c(rep( "hello", 130))
hi<- c(rep( "hi", 130)) 
style <- c(hello, hi, hello, hi)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paste multiple columns together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568662/paste-multiple-columns-together)

Comment: Here are a couple of options: `style <- data.frame(greeting=paste(hello, hi, hello, hi))` or `style <- data.frame(greeting=rep("hello hi hello high", 130))`.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to string concatenation in R is the [`paste`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/paste.html) function. In this case, you just paste the same vectors multiple times:

```r
hello <- rep("hello", 130)
hi <- rep("hi", 130)
result <- paste(hello, hi, hello, hi)
print(result)
```

There are other ways to handle this as well, e.g. using `sprintf`. I suggest consulting `?paste` for details on usage.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help! I will look up paste right away.  However, I think I may have been confusing in my post because I wanted hello to appear 130 times, then hi, and then hello and so on. When I typed in what you just provided, I got hello followed by hi 130 times. Would you know how I would be able to get first hello 130 times and then hi 130 times?  Again thank you for your help

Comment: @Saran use the `c` function to concatenate vectors. It's essential to give examples of desired inputs and outputs when asking questions, to prevent misunderstandings like this.

Comment: Welcome to SO Sara! :-) Shadowtalker's revised code is:
`hello <- rep("hello", 130)
hi <- rep("hi", 130)
result <- c(hello, hi, hello, hi)
print(result)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `rep` with `each`:

```
df <- data.frame(my_col = rep(rep(c("hello", "hi"), each=130),2))
```